# Using completion handler to handle results from calls to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a completion handler to handle results returned from my call to firebase. As of now, when I call the function it jumps directly to `completionHandler(result!)` and returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

```
//View Controller

FireChangePassword(email: (User.current?.email)!, currentPassword: currentPassword!, newPassword: newPassword!, completionHandler: { (result) -> Void in

    if result == ChangePasswordResult.AuthError{
        errorLabel.text = "Incorrect Passworld"
    }
    else if result == ChangePasswordResult.FBError{
        errorLabel.text = "System Error"
    } 
    else if result == ChangePasswordResult.Success{
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
     }
})

//Firebase.swift

enum FirebaseErrors:Error {
        case AuthError
        case FBError
        case Success   
}

typealias CompletionHandler = (_ result:ChangePasswordResult) -> Void

func FireChangePassword(email: String, currentPassword: String, newPassword: String, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {

    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: currentPassword)
    var result : ChangePasswordResult?


    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
        if let error = error {
            // An error happened.
            print("Firebase ReAuthentication Error")
            print(error)

            result = ChangePasswordResult.AuthError

        } else {
            // User re-authenticated.
            FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.updatePassword(newPassword) { (error) in
                if error == nil {
                    print("Firebase Change Password Successful")
                    result = ChangePasswordResult.Success

                }
                else {
                    print(error!)
                    print("Firebase Change Password Failed")
                    result = ChangePasswordResult.FBError
                }

            }
        }
    }

    completionHandler(result!)

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Handle the error inside the closure (which is how it was designed). If there's an error go back to the prior viewController and notify the user, if no error, then proceed. Trying to handle it through throws is going to cause all kinds of asynchronous issues..

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that. I'm trying to return something back from `FireChangePassword ` so I know if there was an error or the request was successful.  But the call to firebase is asynchronous and the function continues to move ahead before firebase returns a result, so my `FireChangePassword` ends up returning a nil value.

Comment: That's correct. Firebase is asynchronous and is not designed to return a value - returns are really for synchronous methods. When Firebase data is valid, it will be within the closure following the Firebase function call. From there you can determine if the password was changed successfully. If it was not, simply go back to the viewController and notify the user, if so, then move ahead to the next controller.  Do all of that inside the closure and the rest will fall into place.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm still not seeing how to implement your solution. My problem is that I created a separate swift file to handle all my firebase calls. I can't pop the view controller from inside the firebase closure since its not defined inside the view controller. So I think I have to customize the firebase call to use a completion handler to let me know whether there was an error or if the request was successful.

Comment: You are going to want to change your strategy since everything in Firebase is asynchronous and expecting return values is going to be problematic. Implement Firebase calls as part of the flow of your app... user enters new password and taps change, call the Firebase function to change password. Inside closure if successful then move to next viewController. If not stay on same viewController and present error message. Trying to implement a completion handler is going to cause the same issue as you absolutely cannot move forward in your UI until that closure occurs with the result of the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified change password process.

Assume the user is looking at a viewController with a password text field where the user can type in an updated password.

They enter a new password and tap the 'Change' button - that button then calls this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

      let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
      let updatedPassword = self.passwordField.text
      user?.updatePassword(updatedPassword, completion: {  error in
         if error != nil {
           print("Error. Show error in current viewController")
         } else {
           print("Login Successful, go to next viewController")
         }
      })
   }
```

Comment: Gotcha. I was always under the impression that you should move as much code out of your view controller as possible. Having a separate swift file for all my firebase calls made sense.

Comment: @Brosef A ViewController is just that - a controller of a view. It's responsible for everything that occurs within that view - button taps or clicks, processing, handling segues, error messages etc. Let the viewController do it's job and let Firebase do the heavy lifting for you. Process Firebase data within closures and move through your UI letting Firebase set the pace. By the sound of it, you've set up a Singleton pattern for Firebase calls - that's probably not necessary in this case. If my answer helped, please accept it so others will know how to handle the same use case.